# A generic error occurred in GDI+ when calling Bitmap.Save()

Tags: powershell

I have a problem with the following code I am trying to run. Basically I have a single source PNG, that I want to copy over all other found PNGs within my current directory, but at the resolution of the original PNG:

```
# Source image to replace all found images with
$sourcePng = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile( 'C:\Path\To\image.png' )

# Get all .png files in the directory
Get-ChildItem *.png -Recurse | Foreach-Object {
Write-Host "Converting $_ to image.png..."
  $png = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap( $_.ToString() )
  
  # Make sure the target size matches the existing image
  $newSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( $png.Width, $png.Height )

  # Dispose to ensure file handles are closed
  $png.Dispose()

  # Create new bitmap object from source png with old image resolution and save
  $newPng = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap( $sourcePng, $newSize )
  $newPng.Save( $_.ToString(), [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Png ) # Errors out here
}
```

However, this yields the following error:

> Foreach-Object: Exception calling "Save" with "2" argument(s): "A generic error occurred in GDI+."
>
> At line:1 char:55
>
> + Get-ChildItem *.png -Recurse | Foreach-Object {
>
> +                                                       ~~~~~~~~~
>
> + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ForEach-Object], MethodInvocationException
>
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExternalException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand

My [initial research](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/52709/C-Bitmap-Save-Generic-GDI-Error) tells me this happens because the target file has an open handle, but calling the `Dispose` function doesn't seem to open it back up again. I've checked and there are no other handles to the file I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution after I wrote this up as I tried a couple more things, and figured this might still spare someone else the headache. Turns out, since my initial code never disposed of the `$png` object, the image was still "locked" as far as GDI+ was concerned. I closed out my PowerShell session, opened a new one, and re-ran my code and the images wrote as expected.